# Split string based on count and words using C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, substring

I need to split string on words and each line should have 25 characters. for example:

string ORIGINAL_TEXT =
                "Please write a program that breaks this text into small chucks. Each chunk should have a maximum length of 25 "

**output should be:**

"Please write a program",

"that breaks this text",

"into small chucks. Each",

"chunk should have a",

"maximum length of 25"

I tried using **substring** - but it is breaking words like

"**Please write a program th**" - wrong

"**Please write a program**" - correct

Please write a program - is only 23 characters, it can take more 2 characters but it would break the word **that**.

```
string[] splitSampArr = splitSamp.Split(',', '.', ';');
string[] myText = new string[splitSampArr.Length + 1];

int i = 0;
foreach (string splitSampArrVal in splitSampArr)
{
    if (splitSampArrVal.Length > 25)
    {
        myText[i] = splitSampArrVal.Substring(0, 25);
        i++;
    }
    myText[i] = splitSampArrVal;

    i++;
}
```

Comment: You split the string with `.` (and `,` and `;`) but as the output, you say you need `"into small chucks. Each"` with a dot inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with:

```
@"(\b.{1,25})(?:\s+|$)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZ6xI0/1)

This regex matches and captures into Group 1 any character but  a newline (with `.`) preceded with a word boundary (so, we only start matching *whole words*), 1 to 25 occurrences (thanks to the limiting quantifier `{1,25}`), and then matches either 1 or more whitespace characters (with `\s+`) or the end of string (`$`).

See a [code demo](http://ideone.com/pjDTOV):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "Please write a program that breaks this text into small chucks. Each chunk should have a maximum length of 25 ";
        var chunks = Regex.Matches(str, @"(\b.{1,25})(?:\s+|$)")
                 .Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
                 .ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", chunks));
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a problem with this regex. If I give length to let's say 5 then it matches only words up to 5 lengths. Ex. "This is my invoice" is broken only into 2 lines but expected was three lines.

Comment: @MukeshKumar You [get 3 lines](https://regex101.com/r/wZ6xI0/7), so there is no problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - this works perfectly in the RegEx builder, but when I try it in C# using a larger number it gives me nothing larger than 127 characters (I need 32K characters, but it breaks it down like this even on smaller numbers like 320).  
var goodsChunks = Regex.Matches(application.Goods ?? "", @"(\b.{1,32000})(?:\s+|$)")
                 .Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
                 .ToList();

Any ideas?

Comment: @Mike I do not know what your input string looks like and what you expect to get.

Comment: Apologies - I think the problem is my text has line breaks in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sentence = "Please write a program that breaks this text into small chucks. Each chunk should have a maximum length of 25 ";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int count = 0;
            var words = sentence.Split(' ');
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                if (count + word.Length > 25)
                {
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    count = 0;
                }
                sb.Append(word + " ");
                count += word.Length + 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```